# Shake gesture and prepare for seuge - Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, pushviewcontroller

I have an `UITabelViewController` (mainViewCtrl), if the user select a cell, a new `UIViewController` (detailViewCtrl) is been pushed into the "Scene", with some detail data regarding the selected cell. - pretty simple stuff.

If the user Shakes the phone, (detailViewCtrl) will been showed with some random detail data.

Here is my `prepareForSeque` code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailViewSeque"])
    {
        int i;

        if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
            UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender;
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.minifigsTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
            i = indexPath.row;
        }else{
            i = arc4random() % [self.collectionOfData count];
        }

            DeatilViewController *dest = [segue destinationViewController];
            dest.data = [self.collectionOfData objectAtIndex:i];

    }

}
```

The Code is pretty simple, nothing fancy. My problem is, if the user shakes the Phone while the transitions between the two ViewController (mainViewCtrl and detailViewCtrl) is going on, I will get this error:

Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for.

I understand why this causes a problem.

But how do I solve it? How do I somehow stop the UIGestureEvent from been fired, while the transitions is active?

Comment: Stop adding the Xcode tag. It does not apply to your question.

Comment: Sorry... But why comment on it?

Comment: Because I removed it once then you put it back. Since I removed it again I wanted to point out why so we don't keep going back and forth. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can add a `boolean property "isInTransit"`.

Set it to `false` in your `viewWillAppear`,

set it to `true` in your `prepareForSegue` (just up to your `int i;`).

And in your `motionEnded` (shake method) test `if (isInTransit=true)` -> don't handle the shake, so don't fire the segue.

Hop this will help

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved my problem.

First I added: `@property BOOL isInTransit;`

Then I added the `viewDidAppear` method to my code, and set `isIntransit` to `true` (viewDidAppear will be called after the transitions has ended.)

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.isInTransit = true;
}
```

Finally I added an if statement to my `motionBegan` method, and set isInTransit to false just before `preformeSegueWithIdentifier` is called:

```
 - (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
        {
            if (self.isInTransit){
                self.isInTransit = false;
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewSeque" sender:self];
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks to **Armand DOM** for helping me out.